# How can I add custom user field values to an article?

Tags: development, articles, user, custom-field

I have created a custom user field named "Gender".

How can I show this field in an article?

I can only manage to show: `username`, `name`, `email` and `User Id`

Here is my current Sourcerer code to access the username:

```
{source} <?php $user = JFactory::getUser(); echo $user->get('name'); {/source}
```

Comment: Have you found any tutorials? Checked the Joomla documentation? Found any pre-existing pages here on JSE? Do you have any coding attempts to share?

Comment: Do you want this gender data to be displayed on all Articles or just one?  If all, then perhaps a template override would be simplest.  Can you explain how and why you are adding this data to your article (this gives your question context).

Comment: if i want to display user name i use {source}
<?php $user = JFactory::getUser();
echo $user->get('name'); 
{/source}    how about user field like Gender?

Comment: i just need to display it only on some pages as pages are restricted depending on groups allocated to users

Comment: What is the identifying column (`field_id`) value for your gender data in `#__fields_values`?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll explain by using a fictitious value.

You will need to reference the `#__users` table and the `#__fields_values` table.

Assuming you are only dealing with logged in users, you will need to acquire the user's id via `JFactory::getUser()->id`.

Then you will need to know the `field_id` that the `gender` value is stored with in the `#__fields_values` table.  For my example below I'll use `28` as the `field_id` value; if you don't know what the correct `field_id` value is for your project, you can search for it in the `#__fields` table the integer that you need to source is in the `id` column.

By performing an INNER JOIN on the two tables, using two conditions in the WHERE clause and calling for a single value in the result set via `loadResult()`, you shall have your `gender` value.

```
try {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $user_id = JFactory::getUser()->id;
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select("b.value AS gender")
        ->from("#__users a")
        ->innerJoin("#__fields_values b ON a.id = b.item_id")
        ->where(["b.field_id = 28", "b.item_id = " . (int)$user_id]);  // $user_id should already be an integer, but cast to be extra safe
    $db->setQuery($query);
    // JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');
    if (!$gender = $db->loadResult()) {
        echo "<p>No Value Found</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>$gender</p>";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // don't show $e->getMessage() to public
}
```

p.s. if you don't want to hardcode the "28" into your query, you can perform a dynamic lookup of the number, but that will require another JOIN with the `#__fields` table -- this is not likely to worth the effort in most cases.